# What is this PHP technique called?

Tags: php

I've seen something like this used in WordPress:

```
if($aVariable=aFunction()){
  // If aFunction() returned true
}
```

What is this called and where can I find more information about it?

Comment: First `aFunction()` is executed, and then its return value is assigned to the variable named `$aVariable` and then the return value is used as the boolean for the if statement. Thats all there is too it.

Comment: Why is this question downvoted? If you've got an issue with the question you should at least have the decency to tell @Linksku why!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Inline assignment" is what I'd call it.

It is equivalent to:

```
$aVariable=aFunction();
if($aVariable){ 
  // If aFunction() returned true 
}
```

And if $aVariable isn't used somewhere else, it is pointless to do this.
So someplace else there needs to a useful read of $aVariable.

There isn't a lot else to say about this, except that it saves a few keystrokes, when you need to check the result of aFunction more than once.

Comment: Quite often, it is also just a typo, accidentally assigning to $aVariable instead of just comparing  (Though in this case, the comment seems to indicate that they meant it that way).

Comment: If the typo is "==" vs "=', yes, that can be true.  WordPress I suspect is probably pretty well tested, so its unlikely to be a typo where the OP found it.

Answer (score 0):

This works because *the value of an assignment expression is the assigned value.*

`$foo = 'bar'` is an assignment *expression*. This expression assigns the value `'bar'` to the variable `$foo` and the expression as a whole also results in the value `'bar'`.

`if ()` expects an *expression* inside the parentheses that it will evaluate to `true` or `false`.

So it boils down like this:

```
if ($aVariable = aFunction())
if (value of expression, which is whatever aFunction() returned)
if (true/false evaluation of value of expression)
```

I don't know if there's a specific name for that.

Answer (score -1):

It's called a "conditional". The [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) has the details.

Comment: Pretty sure the OP is referring to inline function calling inside an `if` expression, and isn't talking about _just_ the `if` statement.

Comment: @nickb: The OP is welcome to clarify her question to explain what she is actually asking...